# how to lock database table in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, locking

database schema :  booking_number(primary,not auto inc), fee (float),...etc

The "booking_number" is to be incremented on every insert. 
This is not auto incremented by the database itself.
The "booking_number" has to be incremented in the code and cannot be done automatically for other reasons.

If I want to insert a row, I will read the last 
"booking_number", increment it and write the new row back to database. 
At the same time another user is also inserting a row, he read the 
last entry of "booking_number" which is the same as I read since I have not 
yet written the new row. He will also increment to the same value and 
write it back. This will lead to a conflict.

So that if i can lock the db tables, no one else can read/write to 
the table until someone have finished with reading and writing the new row .

Can i lock the database table in cakephp ?
Where can i get the reference books or code ??

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You may not need to _lock_ a table for this. Just run your code as your described. When a second process tries to add a new row with the same value, the duplicate key error can be _caught_. When _caught_, re-execute.

Comment: yap,i also think like that. Can customize the error message by creating view/Errors/pdo_error.ctp.  And show message to retry customer.Right?? @AgRizzo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$model = $this->loadModel('Info_Table'); 
// if Info_Table model is not available in your controller
$dbo = $model->getDataSource();

$dbo->execute(
        sprintf('LOCK TABLES %s AS %s WRITE;',
            $model->table,
            $model->alias
        )
    );

 // execute query 
$dbo->execute('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Comment: if my table name is info_table.  Can i try like this??
`$dbo = Info_Table ->getDataSource();    
$dbo->execute(    
        sprintf('LOCK TABLES %s AS %s WRITE;',    
            $model->Info_Table,    
            $model->info_table    
        )    
    );   

  $NewAutoID = Info_Table->find(    
            'first',
            array(
                'fields' => array('booking_number'),
                'order' => array('booking_number'=>'DESC')
            )
        );
$dbo->execute('UNLOCK TABLES');
`.....................................
@u2460470

Comment: $model is a model object. whats the model name??

Comment: model name is Info_Table.  And table name is info_table.

Comment: fiona, I have modified of my code as your model object.

Comment: Even if i've locked tables,
let assume if two users try to book at the same time(exactly same),
it means they can lock tables at the same timing.
So can say it's a deadlock or lock conflict ??
How do i prevent that case ??
Do i need to set lock_time setting in some where ??
Please correct me if I am wrong .Thanks in advance... @u2460470